# Using SED remove first line in matching PHP files (recursively)

Tags: php, sed, terminal

When I want to remove the first line of a specific file that matches a specific start and end I used the following code:

```
sed -i '' '1s/^<\?php $.*-1; \?>//' example.php
```

How would I do this for all files inside the current directory and all of its subdirectories. I've tried *.php but that an illegal operaton apparently...

*** EDIT ***
Ok got a little further with this one. I got the following to work on Mac OS Terminal:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec sed -i '' '1 s/^<\?php $necqwaik.*-1; \?>//' '{}' \;
```

However, executing this on the server itself results in:

```
sed: can't read 1 s/^<\?php $necqwaik.*-1; \?>//: No such file or directory
```

Must be something different with the syntax I should use...

Comment: See the man page for  `find`, specifically for the `-exec` parameter.

Comment: I tried this: find . -name "*.php" -exec sed -i '' '1s/^<\?php $.*-1; \?>' '{}' \; but I get a "unterminated substitute pattern" error

Comment: You need to terminate your pattern `'1s/^<\?php $.-1; \?>//'`...

Comment: What are you doing in the regex provided?

Comment: l'L'l: what do you mean by terminating the pattern?

Comment: Try something simpler on the server, like `sed '1!d' example.php`, and if that works, try a little more complexity.